# Add checks to vue component/template in development mode

Tags: vue.js

I would like to add additional check to a vue component.
They should appears like this:
[image]

Those checks should be executed only in development mode.

Here an example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'FuiButton',
  props: {
    labeled: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
    labeledIcon: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And the check could be, for instance, the two properties cannot be simultaneously true.
Another type of check could be: MyCompB can only exists as child of MyCompA.

Comment: Use .env-files https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack and create a variable eg. APP_ENV=development and then in code check for it if (process.env.APP_ENV == 'development')

Comment: @ege. thank you; this solve the part regarding the limitation to the development mode